# Selenium finds the frame, but does not select it

Tags: iframe, selenium, selenium-rc, frame

I've been trying to select a frame using Selenium, and failing. The HTML code looks like:

```
<html>
<frameset rows="100,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
    <frame scrolling="no" title="Home" name="home_frame" src="http://localhost/home/home_frame.aspx?" marginheight="2" marginwidth="0">
    <html>
        <body id="bodyC" class="Context">
                <table >
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="homeBottom">                                                             
                            <div class="Styledhome">
                                <table style="border-width: 0pt;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="Layout_Center">
                                                    <ul id="hrl01" class="Layout_Tabs" >
                                                        <li id="hr101_Home" class="Layout_ActiveTab">
                                                            <a target="_top" href="http://localhost/home/default.aspx" onclick= "if(pagePreviouslyClicked()){return false;};">Home</a>
```

I do the following:

```
Selenium.SelectFrame("relative=top");
Selenium.SelectFrame("home_frame");
Selenium.Click("link=Home");
```

But it does not select the home_frame. I also tried recording the test using Selenium IDE, and I see only `Selenium.SelectFrame("home_frame");` I tried removing the `relative=top` part, but it still does not select the frame home_frame. When I put `if (Selenium.IsElementPresent("home_frame"))`, it returns true. So, it is finding the home_frame, but does not select it.

Please suggest me if I am doing anything wrong here, and if there is any other way to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do after you select the frame? does the Selenium.SelectFrame("home_frame") cause an exception / timeout to be triggered?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when a frame is selected?

Comment: I updated my question. I am trying to click the Home tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$selenium.click("//a[text()='Home']")
```